# Generators of Cyclic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am having trouble with the following problem.

Let $\operatorname{ord}(a)=n$, for any positive integer $n$, let $\varphi(n)$ denote the number of positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.

For any factor $m$ of $n$, let $$C_m=\{x \in \langle a \rangle : x^m = e\}$$

Prove that an element $x \in \langle a \rangle$ has order $m$ if and only if $x$ is a generator of $C_m$.

I don't know how to show that $x^m=e$ only if $x$ is a generator of $C_m$. What if $x$ wasn't a generator of $C_m$?

Comment: $x^m=e$ for all $x\in C_m$ by definition.

Comment: I was confused because it seemed like it was given. Would I have to show that an element can't have the order m if it is not a generator? If so, how would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First show that $C_m$ has size $m$, then use the fact that the order of an element is equal to the the size of the group genererated by it.

Comment: So basically for x in Cm the ord(x)=m then ∣< x >∣=m must also be true. This shows that the x can only have order m if it is also a generator of Cm.